# Next.js Vercel deployment doesn't run codegen command

Tags: next.js, graphql, vercel

I created a React Next.js project with Typescript on pnpm and using graphql-codegen/typescript to create types. On vercel build, I get module not found error for import of generated types with codegen.

On development server I generate types with 'pnpm gen' command manually from terminal. Probably while next build on vercel, it doesn't run this command. I tried to add it, but couldn't find where to add.

Here is package.json

```html
"scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint",
    "codegen": "graphql-codegen --require dotenv/config --config codegen.ts",
    "gen": "graphql-codegen --config codegen.ts"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.11.1",
    "@emotion/server": "^11.11.0",
    "@graphql-codegen/typescript": "^4.0.1",
    "@graphql-codegen/typescript-operations": "^4.0.1",
    "@graphql-typed-document-node/core": "^3.2.0",
    "@mantine/carousel": "^6.0.19",
    "@mantine/core": "^6.0.19",
    "@mantine/dates": "^6.0.19",
    "@mantine/form": "^6.0.19",
    "@mantine/hooks": "^6.0.19",
    "@mantine/next": "^6.0.19",
    "@react-icons/all-files": "^4.1.0",
    "@saleor/auth-sdk": "^0.8.0",
    "@tabler/icons": "^2.34.0",
    "@tabler/icons-react": "^2.31.0",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.15",
    "date-fns": "^2.30.0",
    "graphql": "^16.6.0",
    "graphql-tag": "^2.12.6",
    "next": "^13.4.3",
    "next-urql": "^5.0.1",
    "options": "^0.0.6",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-is": "^18.2.0",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.3.3",
    "ts-invariant": "^0.10.3",
    "urql": "^4.0.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@graphql-codegen/cli": "5.0.0",
    "@graphql-codegen/client-preset": "4.1.0",
    "@types/node": "^20.2.3",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.6",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.4",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.3",
    "eslint": "^8.41.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "^13.4.3",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "typescript": "^5.0.4"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vercel dashboard, click on your project then the `Settings` tab. On the `General` tab sidebar, you'll find the `Build & Development Settings` section then the project settings collapse area, override the build command as `pnpm gen && pnpm build`, and hit save.